# How to display Highmaps tooltip {point.value} as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I am using Highmaps to display the US county map. I've set up its options to show a simple one-line tooltip over any county that has data associated with it. Here is section of Highmaps options that does that:

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.value}</b><br/>'
},
```

This creates tooltips such as: Autauga, AL: **1**

Instead of this numeric value, I would like to display one of four words : "**Good**", "**Great**", "**Best**", or "**Error**" - corresponding to the {point.value} being 1, 2, 3, or anything else, respectively. So, if the map has a county with a point.value of 2, I would like that to show up in the tooltip as "Autauga, AL: **Great**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the `tooltip` like this

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/az92doc9/)

```
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: '',
  //pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.value}</b><br/>'
  formatter: function() {
    str = "";
    if (this.point.value > 0 && this.point.value < 1) {
      str = "Error";
    }
    if (this.point.value > 1 && this.point.value < 2) {
      str = "Good";
    }
    if (this.point.value > 2 && this.point.value < 3) {
      str = "Great";
    }
    if (this.point.value > 3 && this.point.value < 4) {
      str = "Best";
    }
    if (this.point.value > 4) {
      str = "Error";
    }
    return this.point.name + ': ' +
       str;
  }
},
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for teaching me how to use inline logic like this in JS!